# Where is the main code of convolutional nets?

Tags: lua, deep-learning, torch

Although I want to modify code of convolutional nets, I could not find the main routine of the convolutional nets. The main routine is convolution and pooling.

`SpatialConvolution.lua` had the code below.

```
 96 function SpatialConvolution:updateOutput(input)
 97    backCompatibility(self)
 98    viewWeight(self)
 99    input = makeContiguous(self, input)
100    local out = input.nn.SpatialConvolutionMM_updateOutput(self, input) -- where?
101    unviewWeight(self)
102    return out
103 end
```

So I thought the routine was in `SpatialConvolutionMM`.
However, `SpatialConvolutionMM.lua` had the code below.

```
 65 function SpatialConvolutionMM:updateOutput(input)
 66    -- backward compatibility
 67    if self.padding then
 68       self.padW = self.padding
 69       self.padH = self.padding
 70       self.padding = nil
 71    end
 72    input = makeContiguous(self, input)
 73    return input.nn.SpatialConvolutionMM_updateOutput(self, input) -- where??
 74 end
```

So does anyone know where is `SpatialConvolutionMM_updateOutput`?

Comment: The underlying implementation for the nn package is here; https://github.com/torch/nn/tree/master/lib/THNN/generic. In my torch folder they are located in the directory ```~/torch/extra/nn/generic```.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an open issue [on GitHub](https://github.com/chuanli11/CNNMRF/issues/9) for the same. One of [the solution](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/torch7/CnkUoI6Dh1E/wZrXJaXTAwAJ) mentions upgrading `nn` and `cunn`:

```
luarocks install nn
luarocks install cunn
```

Also, take a look at [this reply](https://github.com/chuanli11/CNNMRF/issues/9#issuecomment-188605005).

Comment: Great! Thank you so much!